# Python Structured arrays instead of many single arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am new to structured arrays, but I think it is that what I need.

I have a numpy array which contains for every entry a minus counter and one array that contains a plus counter. They are filled within a process. At the end of this process I want to divide all plus counter cell per cell through the minus counter and save it in an array with the result of this calculation in every entry.

So I think there is a better way to create three different arrays with the same size. Lets assume my arrays are in this form:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools 

plusArr = np.ones((20 ,39, 90))
minusArr = np.ones((20 ,39, 90))
resultArr = np.zeros((20 ,39, 90))
```

Then the cells are filled with numbers. At the end I doing something like:

```
for i in itertools.product(np.arange(0,20,1),np.arange(0,39,1),np.arange(0,90,1)):
    resultArr[i[0]][i[1]][i[2]] = plusArr[i[0]][i[1]][i[2]]/minusArr[i[0]][i[1]][i[2]]
print(resultArr)
```

This works but in the filling process it is very time consuming to look up the same entry location for both, minus and plus array. So I thought maybe to have a structured array with a triple instead of `i` int entries. In every triple the first entry is the plus counter, the second is the minus counter, and the last entry is 0 until the filling process is finished and it can be filled with the result of the division of plus and minus entry.

As a small side question. If one of my counter entries is 0, then i want to fill the result cell of the entry of the array which has no zero entry at this location. Is there a smart numpy way to do that or just an if condition?

Comment: The answer looks good, but to be sure you should give us a small example - with real values and what you expect.  No one wants to display or test (20,39,90) size arrays.  Also I don't see why you thing `structured` arrays will help you.  For math you have to treat the fields as separate arrays, which you already have.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy allows basic element by element arithmetic operations directly on the arrays.  In addition there is whole bunch of [math routines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.math.html) available.

#### Code:

The element by element division is as simple as:

```
result_arr = plus_arr / minus_arr
```

#### Test Code:

```
import numpy as np

size = (1, 2, 3)
plus_arr = np.ones(size)
minus_arr = np.ones(size) * 2
minus_arr[0, 0, 0] = 3

result_arr = plus_arr / minus_arr

print(plus_arr)
print(minus_arr)
print(result_arr)
```

#### Test Results:

```
[[[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]]

[[[ 3.  2.  2.]
  [ 2.  2.  2.]]]

[[[ 0.33333333  0.5         0.5       ]
  [ 0.5         0.5         0.5       ]]]
```